# Why is `url` `undefined` in the Meteor server production environment, but not locally?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have no clue as to why this is happening, as I can use the `url.parse()` method safely anywhere on the server while developing locally with Meteor.

But the moment I deploy my app (not Galaxy, but via `mupx` - also tried with `mup` before) I get an exception that `url is not defined`.

I know there is a separately bundled `url` package on [Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url), but I though it was already part of Node [v0.10.41](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/master/base/scripts/lib/install_node.sh) running in the Docker container?

What am I missing here?
Do I have to require it separatly?
Why is the module available locally but not on the server?
How do I require it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just assuming `url` is globally defined, or are you calling `Npm.require` to get it?

Comment: I'm not using it in a package (`Npm.require` is not available), just calling it from server code. No need to require it whatsoever locally, calling `url.parse()` works as advertised. Only after deploying does `url` throw the mentioned exception with the exact same code which runs fine locally.

Comment: Actually `Npm.require` can be called from anywhere on the server (not just in a package). I wonder if you do something like [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/url/url_server.js) it would solve your issue.